# Question about sum of l'p spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Is this true or false: $$\bigcup_{1 \leq p < q} \ell^p = \ell^q?$$ I've tried to give an counter example, but I did not get any one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably not what you are looking for but one COULD use some functional analysis to answer the question: If $\ell^q = \bigcup_{p<q} \ell^p =\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \ell^{q-1/n}$ Baire's theorem implies that some $\ell^{q-1/n}$ would be of second category in $\ell^q$ and then the
open mapping theorem for the inclusion $\ell^{q-1/n} \hookrightarrow \ell^q$ would imply the surjectivity of this inclusion. So, all you need to know is that $\ell^p \neq \ell^q$ for $p<q$.

Comment: Killing a mosquito with a thermonuclear device. Nice.

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't those sets you are taking the union of have to be closed with respect to $l^q$ norm to apply Baire?

Comment: Ok davide addresses how to correct for this in the other thread.

Comment: @Evan There's nothing "to correct for". We don't need to suppose anything closed. What we need is 1) $\ell^q$ is complete, 2) we can write the union as a countable union. Since $\ell^q$ is a complete metric space, it is of the second category in itself, and a countable union of sets of the first category is of the first category. So if the union were the entire space, at least one of the $\ell^p,\,p<q$ would be of the second category. But the open mapping theorem asserts that a continuous linear map whose range is of the second category is onto if the domain is an $F$-space.

Comment: @Evan Simple only if you know the theorems. The used form of the open mapping theorem isn't everyday knowledge.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah I see now, was a variant of open mapping theorem I was unaware of. Thanks!

Comment: @Evan Yes, thermonuclear ;)

Comment: Here, the thermonuclear devices also proves that if a closed subspace of $\ell^p$ is contained in the union of the $\ell^q$ for $q\lt p$, then actually it is contained on $\ell_{q_0}$ for some $q_0\lt p$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$x_n = \frac{1}{(n+2)^{1/q}(\ln (n+2))^{1/q} \ln (\ln (n+2))}, \quad n =1,2, \ldots$$
Then $\{x_n\}_1^{\infty} \in \ell^q$, but $\{x_n\}_1^{\infty} \notin \ell^p$ for $p<q$.

Answer (score 0):

For $q=\infty$, anything you can think of likely works as a counterexample.

Otherwise, use the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{n (\log n)^a} < \infty$ for $a>1$ to build counterexamples.