# Prove this inclusion: $\bigcup_{k<p}\ell^k\subsetneq\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$. I have to prove that
$$
\bigcup_{k<p}\ell^k\subsetneq\ell^p.
$$
I am not able to find a counterexample to prove the inequality.

Comment: look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480807/question-about-sum-of-lp-spaces/480843#480843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x(n):=n^{-1/p}\log(n)^{-2/p}$, $n\geqslant 2$.

Since $|x(n)|^p=n^{-1}\log(n)^{-2}$, $x$ belongs to $\ell^p$. 
For $q\lt p$, we can show that $|x(n)|^q\geqslant n^{-\beta}$ for some $\beta\lt 1$ and each $n$ large enough. Indeed, 
$$|x(n)|^q=\frac 1{n^{q/p}(\log n)^{2q/p}}.$$
Now take $\beta\in (q/p,1)$. Then 
$$|x(n)|^q=\frac 1{n^\beta}\cdot \frac{n^{\beta-q/p}}{(\log n)^{2q/p}}.$$
Since $\frac{n^{\beta-q/p}}{(\log n)^{2q/p}}\to \infty$, we have for $n$ large enough $\frac{n^{\beta-q/p}}{(\log n)^{2q/p}}\geqslant 1$.

Comment: How can we show that fact?

Comment: We have that $|x(n)|$ is $1/n$ with an exponent smaller than $1$ ($q/p$) times a logarithm. Taking an other exponent between $q/p$ and $1$, we can get rid of the logarithm.

Comment: I have $\frac{1}{n}^{q/p}\frac{1}{log(n)}^{2k/p}$

Comment: and then? Even if I take an other exponent less than 1?

Comment: I've added details. Is it clearer?